# Figure out what files have changed between local and remote server in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, synchronization, netbeans-7

I am using NetBeans 7.2.1 on a Windows machine for PHP (Drupal) development. I am connecting to a remote dev server via SFTP. So I have the site both locally running AND running on the remote server. I have my setup set to where when I save a file locally it does NOT automatically get uploaded to the remote dev server. I do this so if anyone is viewing the dev server, they are not seeing wonky things as I am developing. Once I get it to a point where I want to upload, I know I can manually upload each file by right clicking and choosing upload, but sometimes I might forget all of the various files I might have worked on. We are not using GIT or SVN unfortunately or this would be easy. Is there a way to do a diff against the directory structure on my local machine vs. what's on the remote server and selectively upload the files that have changed? I know there is "synchronize", but when I did that it didn't give me a chance to see what had changed, it just started synchronizing everything. Is this even possible in NetBeans?

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed the diff button over there that is activated after you click on a file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually yeah I must be because I don't see it. The only buttons that activate when I click a file are "cut" and "copy". If I right click a file I do see that I can choose "Tools/Diff To..." and choose a file to Diff against, but it only allows me to choose a local file. What I was looking for was a way to diff my entire local site against the entire remote site to show me which files have changed, so I know which files to upload to the remote sever. Similar to a GIT status. I am using NetBeans 7.2.1. Maybe this just isn't something it can do.

Comment: Actually, I think you can. I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1 as well. Just like in the first image, right click your project node and select synchronize. Then a window like the second image will popup with multiple files with a status of whether the file is changed. Just click on any file in this window and click the diff button. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Ok yeah sorry, when I clicked Synchronize, I saw my console going crazy and I thought it was automatically synchronizing without my interaction. I was scared that some of my changes locally would automatically go to the remote server, so I aborted. This time I let it run. It took a long time to fetch the remote files though to then allow me to see what's changed but yeah then it showed me which files changed. THANKS!